# jQuery .find() not working in <p>?

Tags: jquery, find

this is my code, HTML:

```
<img src='not right'>
<p class='check'>
  you should not see this line
  <div>
    <img src='yeah'>
  </div>
</p>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.check').text( $('.check').find('img').attr('src') );
});
```

why jQuery cannot find image in div under p? 
p.s.: if replace p with div it working well...

Comment: there is no p tag in html you have shared

Comment: `p` can't contain block elements like `div`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar sorry, i updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `p` cannot contain block elements like `div`, use a `div` instead of `p.check`

```
<img src='not right'>
<div class='check'>
  you should not see this line
  <div>
    <img src='yeah'>
  </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.check').text( $('.check').find('img').attr('src') );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5h90gf7u/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('p.check').text( $('.check').find('img').attr('src') );
});
```